# True or False si un campo en una fila tipo string tiene letras (PRESTO)

Tags: presto

Quiero hacer una query que me devuelva si para una celda de una columna tipo string en una tabla, dicha celda tiene letras.

Supongamos que la tabla se llama **datos** y la columna **valores**.

Ej:

1. A125636
2. 15468
3. 136599
4. B2566B99

Eso me tendría que devolver:

1. True
2. False
3. False
4. True

Esta query la estoy tratando de hacer en Athena (Presto) y no me sale, encontre que se pueden aplicar expresiones regulares pero no las entiendo: https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/regexp.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Di con esta solución, si alguno sabe otra por favor compartala

```
SELECT campo1, campo2, regexp_like(campo2, '[a-zA-Z]') 
as validacion from "base de datos"."tabla"
where regexp_like(campo2, '[a-zA-Z]') = true
```